# Can a shattered planet still hold a breathable atmosphere?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

On Agents of SHIELD Season 5 the Earth is shattered but somehow still holds lakes or oceans and plant life and still has an atmosphere.

Is this scientifically or theoretically plausible/possible and if so how?

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for the Worldbuilding or Physics stack...

Comment: Feel free to ask this question here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, a possible duplicate of : https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21267/what-are-the-requirements-for-an-atmosphere-retaining-moon-with-a-stable-orbit-a

Comment: The Kree are using gravitonium to maintain gravity on shattered Earth.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering your question from a scientific perspective. My points are based on the science of life sustenance and the answer provided by Serban Tanasa ([here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21267/what-are-the-requirements-for-an-atmosphere-retaining-moon-with-a-stable-orbit-a)).

Scientifically, for a celestial body to hold an atmosphere (breathable or otherwise), gravity is the key factor. This gravity is achieved by a molten core of that body. Assuming a planet or any other celestial body in the universe possesses gravity, there is a *POSSIBILITY* of an atmosphere. However, the density of the atmosphere depends on the intensity of gravity. The stronger the gravity, the denser the atmosphere is. So answering the second part of you question, YES. The shattered planet COULD hold an atmosphere and other bodies such as oceans **if and only if** there is gravity.

Moving on to the first part of the question, about the future Earth shown in Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D, it looks something like this -

[image]

The reddish-orange thing seen at the centre is the core of the planet (referring to the representations used by Geologists and also what we know how the core might look like). Thus, there is a slight possibility that the "Quaked" planet Earth may  be able to hold onto a breathable atmosphere and also the Oceans.

But of course it won't be for long as the core is exposed to the cold space and would cool down soon leading to the planet's atmosphere leaving the surface, the oceans freezing and life being completely lost.

Comment: Celestial bodies also have gravitiy, when they do not have a molten core, the only requirement is mass.

Comment: I mean, to be honest, I’m very doubtful that the Earth could retain that shape at all, given its size.

Comment: @TillB yeah. let me make the corrections on that.

Comment: @Adamant well, maintaining that shape is purely imaginary and as you said, doubtful. but not according to fiction apparently :p

Comment: The Kree are using gravitonium to maintain gravity on shattered Earth.

Comment: The core being hot has nothing to do with gravity.

Comment: @OrangeDog - Of course...but the core *does* contain a third of the Earth's mass.